# Build statistics for a tsvector column

Tags: postgresql

I want to build a table where each row contains a string and the number of rows where that string appears as a prefix

Basically I want

```postgresql
select count(*) from "myTable" where tsfield @@ (p||':*')::tsquery
```

for each value of `p` in an array.

How can I write a query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the array and join:

```
SELECT arr.p, count(*)
FROM "myTable"
   JOIN unnest('{...}') AS arr(p)
      ON tsfield @@ (arr.p||':*')::tsquery
GROUP BY arr.p;
```

Comment: Added the group by you forgot. This will count for each value or will create an intermediate table then count as it would for a normal table?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my omission. This will perform a nested loop join, that is, it will go through one table (probably the `unnest`) and scan the other table for matches. Finally, it will group and count the results, just like for a normal table. Use `EXPLAIN` to see how PostgreSQL processes the query.

Comment: The first thing it does is an HashAggregate, then a Nested Loop, I can think of three ways this could be implemented, all of them have the same time complexity, but for auxiliary space one they may have `O(len(p))`, `O(len(p) + len(myTable))`, or `O(len(p)*len(myTable)`, depending on what it will store between two aggregations.

Comment: A hash aggregate is O(len(p)), the nested loop has complexity proportional to the length of `p` and the average number of prefix matches, if you have a full text search index.